# artifact over surfaceview camera preview

Tags: java, android, layout, camera

I have a surfaceview that contains a camera preview and below this is a listview and the preview works but sometimes there is and artifact the same color as the background over the preview now if the list is very long it doesn't have it and if it is shorter than the screen it doesn't have it i cant really explain it i linked to some pictures showing this as i cant upload them, also the surfaceview is created inside the framelayout

layout code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@color/main_background" >



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/send_msg"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

        <ListView 
            android:layout_below="@id/preview"
            android:layout_above="@id/send_msg"
            android:id="@+id/message_list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />

        <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/new_msg"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_msg"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/send_msg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MultiAutoCompleteTextView" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

IMAGES

[Image 1](http://s7.postimage.org/5xau0trqz/device_2012_03_16_204224_copy.png)
[image 2](http://s13.postimage.org/dnr3oushz/device_2012_03_16_204242_copy.png)

I can't figure this out and would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: both images seem to have some "artifact". they both have a grey bar showing in the lower right except in image 2 is much thicker. what is that supposed to be? and why is it only on the right and not on the left?

Comment: The only difference between the two is the amount of items in the listview i cant seem to figure out what it is i tried to change the background color to see what would happen and it changed with it so this leads me to believe it is showing through and i cant explain why